# ACF + contact form 7

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using Contact Form 7 with an ACF field.

In ACF, I created an email field : `email`.

In my Contact Form 7, I have a field called `destination-email`:

`[email* destination-email id:exp-email default:shortcode_attr]`

In my template file i have a line :

```php
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="983" title="Formulaire de contact 1" destination-email="test@example.com"]' ); ?>
```

I need to replace "test@example.com" with the value of the ACF field `email`.

How can I do it?

Comment: you can use this function to retrieve the value : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: You can also help in this use of the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-contact-form-7/

Comment: Here is documentation for a plugin that can redirect contact form 7 : https://redirection-for-contact-form7.com/?pid=9566&aid=5562885&page=documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php values inside the do_shortcode function
In your case it will be like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="983" title="Formulaire de contact 1" destination-email="'.get_field( 'email' ).'"]' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, the field can be populated with the help of post meta

```
[email* destination-email id:exp-email default:default:post_meta ]
```

destination-email = ACF field id.
instead of email, a hidden field can be used. (in case it is being used just for fetching recipient email address.)