# How to set Contact Form 7 fields default value using shortcode attribute?

Tags: shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7

The contact form 7 plugin provides an option to set the default value of a form field using a shortcode attribute (as documented [here](https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-shortcode-attributes/)).  This can be useful to dynamically change the recipient of a notification email using say a `destination-email` field tag in a form and use a shortcode attribute to set its default value dynamically from within a page template using the `do_shortcode` function. So for example, the following shortcode would send the email to xxxxxx@example.com by default,

```
[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="xxxxxx@example.com"]
```

However, it is not clear how to get it to work.

I already read other post where they were asking the same:

[ACF + contact form 7](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287893/acf-contact-form-7)

I must say that the solution didn't work for me. The contact-form keeps sending the emails to the email address set on Contact Form 7 configuration.

This is what i put on my single.php file:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="5" title="Form World Unite" destination-email="'.get_field( 'email' ).'"]' ); ?>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: From a quick skip of the plugin code it might be `recipient=` not `destination-email=`. Or maybe `mail=`. But I'm not sure sorry.

Comment: Why don't you create a second form in the backend with a different recipient? Put the second shortcode in your template - done.

Comment: The idea is having a different contact form for every author who logs in and create a post. So i can't do that.

Comment: I haven't seen anything in the plugin code (Contact Form 7) that allows to set the recipient in the shortcode itself.
What I would do instead is to hook the data when the form is sent and change the recipient on the fly based on the currently logged in user.

Comment: I found another solution, just use the Contact Form 7 Custom Recipient plugin.With this plugin i can change the recipient everytime i create a post, that works for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

the destination-email attribute requires an additional filter to be hooked to work, as detailed in cf7 [doc](https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-shortcode-attributes/) and this forum [thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-emaip-recipient-from-shortcode/#post-9752806), you need to ensure you do the following 4 steps:

1) in addition to the short code attribute,

```
[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="xxxxxx@example.com"]
```

2) you need to,

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_wpcf7', 'custom_shortcode_atts_wpcf7_filter', 10, 3 );
function custom_shortcode_atts_wpcf7_filter( $out, $pairs, $atts ) {
    $my_attr = 'destination-email';
    if ( isset( $atts[$my_attr] ) ) {
        $out[$my_attr] = $atts[$my_attr];
    }
    return $out;
}`
```

3) which assumes you have a field in your form

```
[email* destination-email default:shortcode_attr]
//If you want this field hidden you can use this code instead:
[hidden destination-email default:shortcode_attr]
```

4) and last but not least you need to use the `[destination-email]` mail tag in the 'To:' field in the mail configuration tab.

Comment: Regarding your edit to the question to get this reopened - it doesn't actually change whether this is off-topic or not. I voted to approve the edit, but even with that change, it likely remains off-topic because it is specific to CF7.

Comment: thanks for the heads up @butlerblog, so a question like that should be asked on stackoverflow instead ?

Comment: Yes - plugin specific questions are OK there (as far as I know). If this question was more generally about hooks or shortcodes, then it might be OK on WPSE, but as-is, it's too specific to CF7.

Comment: I see, its kind of a little confusing because there are so many questions as well meta-tags dedicated to plugins on this forum, and the majority of users just don't understand this finer point.